# Oracle - Trigger That When Given One Value Will Fill Another Value in the Same Table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm trying to assist my boyfriend with a project - I have the utmost respect for everyone on here, I hope my lack of knowledge is okay and this question makes sense: He needs a trigger that, when a number is entered in a table, will automatically generate a value in the same table?

For example, if you put $600 under Rent, it would auto-generate 10% of that under 'fee'.

thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER YourTableName_BIU
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Rent ON YourTableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:new.fee := :new.Rent*10; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. The problem is with the "* 10". That will give you a fee of 6000 for the 600 rent not the 60 desired. You just need to shift the decimal point;  change it to "*.10".